# HOWTO: encode WebM using command line VLC?

Tags: html, ubuntu, vlc, webm

I found 1 command line, which claims do the transcode job. but for some reason there is something slightly wrong, it just send ASCII art via terminal, can anyone kindly tell me how to do the transcode via CLI and silently?

```
cvlc aVeryNiceMovie.avi -–sout "#transcode{vcodec=VP80,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=vorbis,ab=128,channels=2}:std{access=file,mux='ffmpeg{mux=webm}',dst=aVeryNiceMoive.webm}"
```

BTW, I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, VLC ver =

```
c2h2@ip-10-128-145-204:~$ vlc -v
VLC media player 1.1.4 The Luggage (revision exported)
```